# Can't inject scope in service (angular 1.5 / es6)

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

```
 const taskServiceModule = angular.module('taskServiceModule');
 class taskService {
  constructor ($scope) {
    console.log($scope)
  }
}
taskService.$inject = ['$scope'];
taskServiceModule.service('tasksService', taskService);
export default taskServiceModule;

const app = angular.module(`app`, [taskServiceModule.name]);
```

I get error, why? who can explain?

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <-
>   tasksService

Comment: The reason it is failing is, you can't inject `$scope` inside `service`

Comment: You can inject only $rootScope or use scope as method parameter

Comment: @Alexandr Skachkov Seks!